# picking a spot in a hashtable RACKET

Tags: hashtable, racket

in racket how can I pick a spot in a hashtable based off a number?
as in i have a hash table and i  want to select things randomly from it so im going to use the size of the hashtable randomly select a number in that range to pick an entry in the hashtable.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a hash table directly, you need to use a structure that is indexable by consecutive integers.

Depending on your hash table, whether you need to keep the original keys in your result, and your performance needs you can either use `hash-keys`, `hash-values`, `hash->list` or you could create a new hash replacing all the keys with consecutive integers:

Examples:

*hash-keys*

```
(define (take-hash-random1 h n)
  (let* ((keys (hash-keys h)) (len (length keys)))
    (for/list ((i (in-range n)))
      (hash-ref h (list-ref keys (random len))))))

(take-hash-random1 ht 5)
=> '(yellow yellow red yellow yellow)
```

*hash-values*

```
(define (take-hash-random2 h n)
  (let* ((vals (hash-values h)) (len (length vals)))
    (for/list ((i (in-range n)))
      (list-ref vals (random len)))))
```

*hash->list*

```
(define (take-hash-random3 h n)
  (let* ((lst (hash->list h)) (len (length lst)))
    (for/list ((i (in-range n)))
      (cdr (list-ref lst (random len))))))
```

*new hash table*

```
(define (take-hash-random4 h n)
  (let* ((vals (hash-values h)) 
         (len (length vals))
         (newh (make-hash (map cons (range len) vals))))
    (for/list ((i (in-range n)))
      (hash-ref newh (random len)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(random n)
```

Returns an integer in the range of 0 up to n-1 included.
So you can do the following

```
  (define ht (hash 0 'red 1 'yellow 2 'blue))
  (hash-ref ht (random 3))
```

But you need to be careful the following example might fail.

```
  (define ht2 (hash 0 'red 1 'yellow 3 'blue))
  (hash-ref ht2 (random 4))
```